# Is my database secure? / What does "=Tc/postgres" allow?

Tags: postgresql

Given the following...

```
iproductiondb  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                 +
               |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres        +
               |          |          |             |             | iproduction=CTc/postgres
```

Are the postgres and iproduction roles the only roles that have any type of access to iproductiondb ?

=Tc/postgres is making me wonder if I need to fix something?

Answer (score 4):

`=Tc/postgres` means that postgres has granted CONNECT and TEMPORARY privileges to PUBLIC. You can revoke these privilege with :

```
revoke connect on database iproductiondb from public;
revoke temporary on database iproductiondb from public;
```

In general you should also check `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Would that mean other users could select / update ?

Comment: TEMPORARY means creating temporary tables. AFAIK this does not give SELECT OR UPDATE privilges on database objects. But you should also check privileges at schema level with `\dn+` and privileges on tables with `\dp+`.